# How to recognize .delete in editingStyle in Swift 3 to delete cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

this all my func that connected to my table view. Why I can't delete row?

I also do in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "incTV")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "X"

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text =  "Y"

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        arr.remove(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What isn't working?

Comment: Your code is working, what is it that you´re having trouble with?

Comment: when I swipe .. its not doing anything

Comment: You´re firing the event when you click on the delete button. Do you see a delete button?

Comment: I swipe on the screen and nothing..

Comment: Are you swiping in the correct direction?

Comment: yes, I tried to both directions

Comment: Did you implement all of the required delegate methods that support row deletion? It's all covered in the documentation. Update your question with all of the relevant methods and tell us which ones are actually called when you swipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure your table has a delegate set, and that your delegate method is in the delegate class/controller.

Second, try to use `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method and return true.